# copy_from_user()/__get_user() works fine within ioctl, but failed outside ioctl

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently doing experiments with a kernel module.

I wrote a function that takes in a pointer to a structure (in user space) as a parameter, with the aim to copy that structure from user space to kernel space; hence, I need `copy_from_user` or `__get_user`.

The definition of the structure is quite simple:

```
struct A {
    int a;
};
```

The function in my kernel module aims to get the value of a, and return its value, which is as follows (with two approaches):

```
static int foo(struct A __user *arg)
{
    int num, ret; 

    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, arg, sizeof(struct A)))
        return -EFAULT;
    
    /* approach1: directly copy the value from user space */
    ret = __get_user(num, (int __user *)&arg->a);
    if (ret) return -ENOMEM;

    /* approach2: allocate space for struct A, then copy the whole struct */
    struct A *tmp = kmalloc(sizeof(struct A), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!tmp) return -ENOMEM;

    ret = copy_from_user(tmp, (const void __user *)arg, sizeof(struct A));
    if (ret) return -EFAULT;

    num = tmp->a;
    kfree(tmp);
    
    return num;
}
```

No matter which approach I use, this function works fine in `ioctl`. Below is a snippet of the code in `ioctl`:

```
long foo_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    struct A __user *tmp_struct;
    int ret;
    ...

    switch (cmd) {
    case IOC_FOO:
        ret = foo((struct A __user *)arg);
        break;
    ...
    }
    
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

However, when I move `foo()` into another function `foo2()`, it will fail on either `__get_user()` or `copy_from_user()`. The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
int foo2() 
{
    int val;
    ...
    struct A __user *addr = the address of struct A in user space
    val = foo(addr); /* this is where error occurrs */
    ...
}
```

Note that the code is a simpler version of my experiment. `foo2()` is called through another cmd in `ioctl()`, issued by the same process. I got the address of struct A - `addr` from user space using another ioctl() cmd, which is irrelevant to this question. I have already checked that the address of struct A in user space is correct (by printing the addresses both in user space and kernel space), which makes me quite confused - why a valid user space address would lead to error in `copy_from_user()` or `__get_user()`?

Why `foo()` works in `ioctl()` but does not work in `foo2()`?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `foo2` called from?  Are you sure it's from a system call issued by the same process?

Comment: @NateEldredge: ```foo2``` is called from another cmd in ```ioctl```, issued by the same process.

Comment: @EthanL. can you show how ```foo2()``` was called ?

Comment: @Khaled: ```foo2()``` was called by ioctl, which starts a kernel thread. Inside the thread, it first gets the address of ```struct A``` in user space, then tries to copy the whole struct using ```copy_from_user()```. I have checked that the address of ```struct A``` in user space passing in to the kernel is correct. I know what I did may not make any sense, as I have mentioned, I am just playing with a simple module and doing some small experiments with it. That's why I'd like to test the kthread interface as well, as I have never tried to create a kernel thread before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"which starts a kernel thread. Inside the thread" oops there's your mistake. You can only call copy from/to user from the thread that issued the system call or fault or otherwise got to kernel space from userspace. In a way, this is the same userspace thread just in kernel space so the calls work. From a new kernel thread you're not on that thread and not associated with that particular userspace process anymore so it doesn't know.

You're lucky it failed. In some cases it may have become associated with init and trashed init's memory leading to a panic.